# What is the meaning of "informieren" in this context?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, vocabulary

I am working on a software development project where I am using IPERKA as a method to implement my project, which I found only in German language. But I feel inform is not a suitable word for informieren and couldn't think of any better word as well. May be Information collection .. Any help would be highly appreciated .

For example

> Informieren und Vorbereiten  : In english Inform and Prepare doesn't
> looks suitable

may be Information collection(Information Gathering ) and Preparation..
But since I am very bad in German .. any suitable translation would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I changed the question title. Before it sounded very much like a question about the English language.

Answer (score 6):

"informieren" and "to inform" are kind-of "false friends": in German "informieren" has two meanings: reflexively used ("sich informieren") means "to gather information", non-reflexively used it means "to pass information". English only uses this latter meaning:

- "Ich informiere mich über ..." <sub>I learn about...</sub>
- "Ich informiere jemanden über ..." <sub>I inform someone about ...</sub>

For your purpose "assess (the situation)" or "learn" is perhaps a good choice.

Notice that "realisieren"-"realize" and "kontrollieren"-"control" further down your chart pose similar problems: I'd suggest "to implement" for "realisieren" and "to reassess" or "to follow-up" for "kontrollieren".

Comment: +1 most accurate answer IMHO

Answer (score 1):

In this context **research** seems the most natural to me.

- **research** (What needs to be done?)
- **gather ideas** (Which ways of doing xy are available?)
- **decide** (What are we about to do?)
- **development**
- **assess** (Everything done as discussed in 3.?)
- **evaluation** (How did we do? Is there something to improve?)

Answer (score 1):

Right away, I would have chosen "gather information" or "gather facts". Two ways, which hadn't been mentioned yet.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *Erkundigungen einholen* or, if it should be a verb only: *erkundigen*, for it relates more to the gathering of information.

<sup>(I hope I have not misinterpreted the question and you are looking for a German alternative; otherwise, the question would be off-topic anyway.)</sup>